# check if the user is owner of current page

Tags: functions, shortcode

I am struggling with this little problem. I have a user profile page and I want to change some of the content based on whether it is my own profile og someone elses. This is my code to add a shortcode which eventually will call other shortcodes.

```
function is_mine_func() {
if (is_author() ) {
    echo 'it is my site';
   // echo do_shortcode('[wpfepp_submission_form form="2"]' );
    }
else 
    {
        echo 'its not your site';
    //echo do_shortcode('[userpro template=postsbyuser postsbyuser_mode=grid]' );
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'minminmin', 'is_mine_func' );
```

I have a feeling that is_author is not the right way to do so since I always get the 'its not your site' message no matter if I am the author of the page or not.

Should is_author() not evaluate if I am the author of 'this' page or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Codex, [`is_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) checks to see if you're on an Author Archive page (ie, a page listing all the posts/pages/etc that a given user has authored). If you're on any other type of page, `is_author()` will return `false`.

What you're looking for sounds more along these lines:

```
if ( in_the_loop() )
{
    get_currentuserinfo();
    print ( get_the_author() === $GLOBALS['current_user']->display_name )
        ? 'It is my site.'
        : 'It is not my site.';
}
```

This code must be used in The Loop.

### References

- [`is_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author)
- [`get_the_author()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author)
- [`get_currentuserinfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)
- [`in_the_loop()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop)

Comment: This makes sense too. But it is as if it always evaluate as false. aka. It is never my site

Comment: Thanks you are right. We have some plugin functions that overwrite this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to use author IDs rather than the username:

```
if ( get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) {
    echo "It is my site.";
else {
    echo "It's not my site";
};
```

### References

- [get_current_user_id](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id)
- [get_the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

Comment: I considered comparing IDs, but `get_the_author()` returns the author's display name, so that's what I went with. Also, [`the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta) *displays* the metadata; you should probably use [`get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) instead.

Comment: Changed answer use get_the_author_meta... silly me!